# Cannot install vue

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, vuejs2

I usually perform fresh re-installs of packages after a period of non-use, but when I came to perform a fresh install of Vue.js and vue-cli I tried to perform a `vue init` on a new project but was told that vue was not recognised as an operable or batch file etc.

It is possible that I created a problem when I uninstalled vue-cli, which removed something like 250 packages. Subsequent reinstall only installed 1 package, but I was then unable to get any response from the `vue init` command other than the above.

I have tried every workaround I could find on SO and elsewhere which boils down to the following: -

- Upgrading node and npm
- Upgrading git
- Cleaning the npm cache

One consistent error message in my attempts to perform `npm install vue` was that I lacked a `package.json` file in my `C:/Users/user` folder (I am said `user` and I have administrator privileges). I ran `npm init` to create a blank package.json file in that folder but that didn't work either.

The root problem seems to be that nothing I do re-installs a `vue.cmd` file in my `AppData/Roaming/npm` folder, even though this path is properly installed in my environment variables. I have looked if this file has been installed elsewhere on my machine, but it hasn't.

Is it possible to manually download a vue.cmd file and put it exactly where it needs to sit, i.e. in my `AppData/Roaming/npm` folder? I googled this to no avail. All this is while running Command Prompt as an administrator.

Is anyone else having this problem? Is there something with another JS framework which is currently blocking Vue from being properly installed? (I have also developed projects in React and Angular5.)

Just as an update, this is the `package.json` file I currently have in my `C:/Users/user` folder after running `npm init` from that folder: -

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^5.8.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: TL;DR. Sometimes, summarize helps

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have `vue-cli` installed on your machine

But without any error messages it's impossible to tell.

try `npm install -g vue-cli@2.9.3`

then run `which vue-cli` to check the location